# Fastest way to extract all bands from raster at once (python/gdal)

Tags: python, numpy, gdal

I have some hyperspectral imagery with a large number of bands, which I want to do analysis on. My script needs to be able to access all the bands at once.

Currently, I'm achieving this with the following:

```
bands = np.asarray([dataset.GetRasterBand(n+1) for n in range(dataset.RasterCount)])
```

This works fine, but it seems that this step is taking up a significant amount of time in my processing workflow, and I suspect there is a better way to do it. Also, I am under the impression that it is poor practice to use list comprehensions with numpy in this way (?).

Do numpy or gdal have any built-in methods that can make this faster?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In GDAL there is a distinction between the bands, and the data in the band. Assuming you want the latter, just use:

```
data = dataset.ReadAsArray()
```